# collapsible navbar will not work (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with this for awhile. The navbar shows up just fine, but the functionality is not there. Here is the code:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "navigation" id = "my-navbar">
   <div class = "container">
      <div class = "navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "index.html">WM</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "myNavbar">
         <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href = "https://github.com/williamjmiller" target="_blank">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href = "documents/myresume.pdf" target = "_blank">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#bottom">Contact Me</a></li>
            <input type = "button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" value = "Blog" onclick = "relocate_blog()" id = "blog-button">
            <script>
               function relocate_blog() {
                 location.href = "blog.html ";
               }
            </script>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!--End Container -->
</nav>
<!-- End Navbar -->
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "navigation">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "index.html">WM</a>
      </div>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "myNavbar">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href = "https://github.com/williamjmiller" target="_blank">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href = "documents/myresume.pdf" target = "_blank">Resume</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#bottom">Contact Me</a></li>
          <input type = "button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" value = "Blog" onclick = "relocate_blog()" id = "blog-button">
            <script>
            function relocate_blog() {
              location.href = "blog.html ";
            }
            </script>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!--End Container -->
  </nav><!-- End Navbar -->
```

Comment: @William Miller remove id="my-navbar" from nav tag & put data-target="#myNavbar" in button tag.  https://jsfiddle.net/tarunjoshi/quoyhbqk/

Comment: Thanks @tarun joshi ! Unfortunately it still seems to be misbehaving with the changes made. Any other ideas?